# windows line endings coming in ionic build files

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova, parallels

I'm using visual studio to launch an ionic application in my iOS simulator.  I'm running visual studio in windows 10 via parallels.  I have setup remotebuild from the mac side but when I try to launch in the iOS simulator I get the following error:

> Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Hook
>   failed with error code 127: {my home
>   directory}.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/10310/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js

I know I can fix this specific file but that doesn't help as every time I perform a build the problem will occur again. My co worker with a similar setup is not seeing this issue and does not have the ^M line endings ... so what could I have setup wrong?  Is there a way to fix this?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: did you ever fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and was able to find a workaround to that problem. What I did was to change the line endings of the file *010_add_platform_class.js*  to LF instead of CRLF **on my Windows machine**.

As Visual Studio doesn't have an option to change line endings as far as I know, I've used Visual Studio Code to open the file. There you have a label in the bottom right of the status bar that says *CRLF*. When you click that you can change the line endings to *LF*.

After doing that everything worked fine.